# TypeLoadException After upgrade visual studio to version 16.4.0 Preview and .net core SDK 3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, typeloadexception

I just have updated the visual studio to version 16.4.0 preview 2 along with .NetCore SDK to 3.1, after upgrade my application starts failing and raising LoadType Exception at just login page.

I have also updated the plugins used in the project from NuGet, also have done fresh installation of sdk's and VS but non of these helping in solving the problem,

I have search the google but did not find any clue, seems like the only solution is to downgrade the system.

Following is the exception message.
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

Does anyone had any clue whats wrong with the upgrade process?

Comment: Do an `dotnet --list-sdks` and `dotnet --list-runtimes` and see if the 3.0 (or whatever version your app was build against) runtime is still installed. Sounds like your application is built against an old version and now rolls forward to 3.1 (starting with 3.0, the SDK installer replaces the previous 3.0 version isntead of adding a new one - at least this was true for 3.0-previews). If your app was a 3.1, then its mostlikely because of breaking changes in the 3.1 previews, since the new sdks just replace the old preview instead of side-by-side install

Comment: thanks for you reply but that's not my case, sdk and runtimes are installed.

Comment: Any updates on this issue? i have the same exception with everything latest.

Comment: Comes with the solution, sorry for my late response.

What I have done wrong is that i have used an internal library property that has been changes in the upgraded version, what should I have to used the public member of the library, "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest" was something internal to library which I have seen VIA debugging, so I used this in my code, that part was wrong. I have to change the line where exception is raising